# MySQL unknown column 'useranswers.userid' in ON clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting the error "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'useranswers.userid' in 'on clause'" using the below MySQL code

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kumianswers 
INNER JOIN users on useranswers.userid = users.id 
INNER JOIN kumiquestions on useranswers.questionid = kumiquestions.id 
WHERE login = '".$username."' and users.level <= 3 and categoryid = 1;
```

There is a table called 'useranswers' and it does indeed have a column called 'userid' and there is the 'users' table that does have a 'id' field. This is a modification from an old line of code that does work. We had to remake the tables to fit the new system being developed. The old working code was....

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM answers
INNER JOIN users on answers.ans_user = users.user_id 
INNER JOIN questions on answers.ans_question = questions.quest_id 
WHERE username = '".$username."' and ans_level <= 3 and quest_type = 1;
```

Comment: You can only reference tables that are mentioned in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: @chris3spice Remember to select an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark underneath the place where it shows the number of votes.

Answer (score 4):

You're selecting from `kumianswers` and joining with `users` and `kumiquestions`, but you try to compare with a column from `useranswers` — a table you're not joining with.

Comment: That makes sense, in the old system it was not broken up into as many tables... Should have just tried to make it from scratch and I may have realized it.

Comment: @chris3spice I can see that you have asked 13 questions, but only accepted the answer to one question. Remember to accept answers to questions that solve the problems. This will both reward the poster and inform others that your issue has been resolved. And it even gives you reputation, too. :)